# Remove postcode from Woocommerce cart shipping calculator

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In Woocommerce, I have been able to remove postcode checkout field using this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    unset($address_fields['postcode']);

    return $address_fields;
}
```

How can I remove the postcode field from the shipping calculator in cart page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done adding the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_postcode', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_address_fields', 999, 1 );
function custom_override_address_fields( $address_fields ) {

```
// set as not required
$address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;

// remove validation
unset( $address_fields['postcode']['validate'] );

return $address_fields;
```

}

(this is the real code that devalidates the postcode)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).