# Show shipping calculator postcode field only for specific countries in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am using [Remove postcode from Woocommerce cart shipping calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657296/remove-postcode-from-woocommerce-cart-shipping-calculator/51657358#51657358) answer code which I tested and works fine.

But the problem is that it hides the postcode of the Shipping Calculator for all countries.

What I would like is to hide it for all countries EXCEPT one: Belgium (BE).

Is this possible? How can I make it work for all countries except Belgium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can dynamically hide and show the postcode field based on the selected country with some jQuery:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'show_shipping_calculator_postcode_field_based_on_country', 50 );
function show_shipping_calculator_postcode_field_based_on_country() {
    if ( ! is_cart() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            $(document.body).on('change', 'select[name="calc_shipping_country"]', function() {

                let country = $(this).find( 'option:selected' ).val();
                let postcode = $(this).closest( 'p#calc_shipping_country_field' ).siblings( 'p#calc_shipping_postcode_field' ).find('input');

                if ( country !== 'BE' ) {
                    postcode.prop('disabled', true);
                    postcode.attr('value', '');
                    postcode.hide();
                } else {
                    postcode.prop('disabled', false);
                    postcode.attr('value', '<?php echo WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode(); ?>');
                    postcode.show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

This clears the value of the postcode field, disables it and hides it when the selected country is not Belgium.